# Popcorn.js fade in/out subtitles

Tags: javascript, html5-video, popcornjs

I'm looking for a way to have a nice fade in and out of the subtitles on a video using Popcorn.js.

As for of now, it seems like it's just a hard cut between making the subtitle inline or display none.

```
          start: function( event, options ){
    options.innerContainer.style.display = "inline";
    options.showSubtitle( options, options.text );
  },

  end: function( event, options ) {
    options.innerContainer.style.display = "none";
    options.innerContainer.innerHTML = "";
  },
```

How could I manage this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use fadeIn() and fadeOut jquery methods. Put the subtitles into a div and it's done.

```
// Start
$('#mysubtitleDIV').fadeIn('slow');

// End
$('#imagediv').fadeOut('slow');
```